# Adding button to Python graphics.py window

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I have a project which is making a simple breakout game with python. I am having a problem with making a button on a graphic window.

```
from graphics import*
win = GraphWin("win",200,150)
def buttons():
    rectangle = Rectangle(Point(30,85),Point(60,55))
    rectangle2 = Rectangle(Point(170,85),Point(140,55))
    rectangle.setFill("blue")
    rectangle2.setFill("blue")
    rectangle.draw(win)
    rectangle2.draw(win)
```

Here, How can I make those rectangles as buttons which represent the movements "Left",& "Right"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simple solution for a red left button, a green right button and an "Exit" button to quit the program.  I've rearranged the rectangles that represent the buttons such that P1 is the lower left corner and P2 is the upper right corner.  This simplifies the test to see if the clicked point was inside the button.  (You can make the code more sophisticated to remove this assumption.)

```
from graphics import *

WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200, 150

win = GraphWin("Simple Breakout", WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)

def buttons():
    left = Rectangle(Point(25, 55), Point(55, 85))  # points are ordered ll, ur
    right = Rectangle(Point(145, 55), Point(175, 85))
    quit = Rectangle(Point(85, 116), Point(115, 146))

    left.setFill("red")
    right.setFill("green")
    text = Text(Point(100, 133), "Exit")
    text.draw(win)

    left.draw(win)
    right.draw(win)
    quit.draw(win)

    return left, right, quit

def inside(point, rectangle):
    """ Is point inside rectangle? """

    ll = rectangle.getP1()  # assume p1 is ll (lower left)
    ur = rectangle.getP2()  # assume p2 is ur (upper right)

    return ll.getX() < point.getX() < ur.getX() and ll.getY() < point.getY() < ur.getY()

left, right, quit = buttons()

centerPoint = Point(WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2)
text = Text(centerPoint, "")
text.draw(win)

while True:
    clickPoint = win.getMouse()

    if clickPoint is None:  # so we can substitute checkMouse() for getMouse()
        text.setText("")
    elif inside(clickPoint, left):
        text.setText("left")
    elif inside(clickPoint, right):
        text.setText("right")
    elif inside(clickPoint, quit):
        break
    else:
        text.setText("")

win.close()
```

If you click the red or green buttons, you'll get "left" or "right" printed in the center of the window, otherwise no text appears:

[image]